# Импорт внешних файлов в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

1. Есть два файла(**1.ts**, **2.ts**), лежат на одном уровне(рядом друг с другом).
   Так работает: `import a from './2';`
   А так уже нет: `import a from '2';`

В чем причина? Нужно указывать дополнительные параметры в **tsconfig.js** или если я компилирую через CLI? Если да, то какие?

2. Как импорировать(используя es2015-синтаксис) js-файлы?
   Например, я хочу с помощью npm поставить lodash и импортировать подобным образом:    `import _ from 'lodash';`   Как это сделать?

Comment: судя по справке: если файл `.ts` - то к нему полный путь нужен, если `.d.ts` - то можно по имени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее простым решением будет:

1. Используем менеджер пакетов для TypeScript, такой как [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings). Устанавлием глобально: `$ npm i typings -g`.
2. Устанавливаем lodash локально(в папку с проектом): `$ npm install lodash -D`.
3. Устанавливаем ***.d.ts** файл определений c помощью Typings:
   `$ typings install lodash -D`.
4. В файле 1.ts добавляем [директиву](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), в которой будет прописан путь к файлу определений: `/// <reference path="typings/modules/lodash/index.d.ts" />`
5. Используем ES6 синтаксис импорта для подключения библиотеки:
   `import * as _ from 'lodash';`